# Why tags in contact form are not working?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

On my webpage, I have a contact form, which sends messages directly to my mail. Unfortunately, I receive everything in one line, tags are not working and also when I want to reply to that mail, instead of mail there is:

```
To:my@mail.comrnReply-TornContent-Typetext/html

To: PHP/7.2.7 <>
```

I am totally lost, where should be a problem. Does anyone know what's going on, please?

```php
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  if ( (isset($_POST['email'])) && (strlen($_POST['message']) > 5) ) {

    $receiver = "my@mail.com";

        $to      = $receiver;
        $subject = 'New message - mypage.com';
$message = 'New e-mail sent by contact form, from mypage.com.<br> Contact: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br>Text :<br> ' . $_POST['message'] . '';
        $headers = 'From: ' .$receiver."rn" .
            'Reply-To: ' .$email."rn" .
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            $warning = '<div class="sent"><p class="success">Your message was successfully sent. Thanks for your time.</p></div>';
      $_SESSION['hlaska'] = $warning;
        } else {
            $warning = '<p class="error">Unexpected error.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $warning = '<p class="error">You did not fill all fields.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You CSS classes (sent, error) won't work there.

Comment: update like `'<p class="error">You didn\'t fill all fields.</p>';` you have an error here `don\'t` change it like this and try.

Comment: Check this link also. How to use `rn` in your header and how you can use header. https://www.codexworld.com/send-beautiful-html-email-using-php/

Comment: I still don't see, where should be a problem..
@GhanuBha I have tried to rewrite apostrophe part, but still has the same problems..

Comment: Can you please add you latest code ?

Comment: @GhanuBha I have edited it, just used "did not" instead of "didn't"

Comment: Replace `rn` with `\r\n` and check.

Comment: I've tried, but whenever I rewrite it and hit "save", it says "operation ended successfully", but change back